# I used fsck and now I can't change the favourites?

Tags: boot, fsck, favorites

My computer took too long to boot, so I turned it off and back on again, then it demanded I repair something.

I learned online that I needed to fix some errors in my boot drive by using `fsck -vf /dev/sda2`, and now my keyboard has been reset to US, I can't change my favourites, nor my wallpaper!

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please keep rants out of the question ;-) focus on the problem

Comment: Confirmed: I am not able to change any default settings.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:
The issue was that an important file got corrupted, so it couldn't save changes from the default settings. To fix the issue, I opened the terminal and typed in: "nautilus .config" and then navigated to dconf and deleted the user file.

This will not restore previous settings, but will enable the user to save changes to settings. You do not even need to reboot. Source:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165485

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)